# Google Cloud App Engine File Storage Backup

Tags: cloud, backup

I need help regarding Google Cloud. I have deployed my Node and React app on Google Cloud App Engine. I uploaded images on Google Cloud (Node server) but when I deployed again those previous images replaced by new Node image folder.

so is there any way so I can keep my old pictures?

Answer (score 2):

Files upload in the Google App Engine is not a recommended solution from Google. Please follow this link: [google-app-engine-file-upload.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload)

You should use Cloud Storage to store dynamic uploaded files.